# Inconsistent results with subsetting data in R

Tags: r, subset

I have a dataframe that has dates in the format `YYYY/MM/DD`. I tried subseting it in two ways and got different values:

Method 1:

```
 a <- mydata[(mydata$Date > 2010-01-01),]
```

Result:

This gave me results that include dates in 2008, 2009, etc.

Method 2:

```
 a <- mydata[(mydata$Date > 2010/01/01),]
```

Result:

This gave me the correct results.

As you can see, the difference is the way I format the dates - "/" vs "-". Can someone explain to me what the difference is? The dates in the dataframe itself are in the form of `YYYY-MM-DD`, which is why I used the hyphen in Method 1.

Comment: Initially they were factors and I changed them to Date

Comment: Neither of those methods should work with a proper date value (or at least not in the way you are expecting). It would be helpful if you included a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input so we can replicate the behavior. A proper comparison would look like `a <- mydata[(mydata$Date > as.Date("2010-01-01"),]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your dates are character values (and not factors or Dates which unfortunately look just the same when printed to the console) then you can use ">" or "<" or "==" but to do so the expression for the value needs to be quoted. Otherwise you just get the arithmetic value of

```
> 2010-01-01
[1] 2008
```

No error will be thrown because you can compare numerics and character vectors but the results will not be to your liking:

```
> 2010-01-01 > "2007-01-01"
[1] TRUE
```

So to be safe and get meaningful results, try this:

```
 asub <- mydata[(as.character(mydata$Date > "2010-01-01"), ]
```

The `as.character` will convert either factor- (or Date)-classed vectors to character.